# Logic inside BuilderPattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Recently I came across with a builder pattern that intrigued me.

So, I have an `EntityBuilder` which builds an `Entity`, but it doesn't return the entity. Here is the method signature:

```
public void build();
```

Instead, inside the `build()` method, it delivers the new object created, the `Entity`, to a `CacheImplementation` instance to store it.
Note: the `CacheImpl` is injected in the builder's constructor.

```
public void build(){
    //create new entity
    cacheImplementation.add(entity);
}
```

Does this sounds like best practice?

## Later edit 0

```
public interface EntityBuilder {

    void setProperty0(PropertyObject propertyObject0);
    void setProperty1(PropertyObject propertyObject1);
    void setProperty2(PropertyObject propertyObject2);
    //...

    void build();
}

public class EntityBuilderImpl implements EntityBuilder {
    
    PropertyObject propertyObject0;
    PropertyObject propertyObject1;
    PropertyObject propertyObject2;
    //...

    // setters for all properties
    @Override
    public void build(){
        //create new entity
        cacheImplementation.add(entity);
    }
}
```

The builder is used in the following way:

```
public class EntityProcessor{
  private EntityBuilderFactory entityBuilderFactory;//initialized in constructor

  void process(EntityDetails entityDetails){
       EntityBuilder entityBuilder = this.entityBuilderFactory.getNewEntitytBuilder();
       //..
       // entityBuilder.set all properties from entityDetails
       entityBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

Note: the cacheImpl instance just stores the entities in a `List<>` which is accesses every N seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this sounds like best practice?

The traditional builder pattern doesn't store the created object anywhere, it simply returns it.

I can imagine a variation where the builder also has a role of instance control to avoid creating duplicate objects, and managing a store of immutable objects.

The decision to not return an instance could be to make it clear that the method has a side effect. If the method returned the object, it might mislead to thinking that it's a traditional builder without side effects, when that's not the case here.

In any case, all this is just speculation, as we haven't seen the rest of the code where this is used and the way it is implemented and used. We don't have enough context to really judge.
There's nothing wrong with inventing new patterns, but it can be done well or badly.

Comment: Variations of traditional design patterns sounds nice. I've added a small snippet of code to see what i've meant. Is this enough to judge?

Comment: No, not enough. The more interesting part will be the use of the builder and the cache. Btw a list as a cache sounds odd. I expected a map.

Comment: It's not a List, it's a Set cleared at N seconds, every time when processing starts. I've edited again how the builder is used.

Comment: Still far from enough. Actually I'm wondering if there's a builder pattern here at all, or if you're just calling it that way because the class name contains the word "builder". For example, in the interface there are void methods to set properties, but the builder pattern typically has a *fluent* interface, where the setters return the builder itself, allowing chaining.

Comment: You are right. The naming may induced me in error. Every so called "Builder" interface has only void methods, they don't return the builder itself. The build method just calls the constructor of the entity to create the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar `void build()` method in the [JCodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel.html) class. As you can see it throws [IOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) because of the [resources it manages](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ReleasingResourcesInJava):

```
public void build(File destDir,
                  PrintStream status)
           throws IOException
```

You basically ask it to carry out the operation for you and if no error is present - you can continue with the workflow.

Comment: @Vlad it'll be nice if you remove the "thanks" comment. The site policy for helpful answers is voting those up. Lets keep it clean. I'll remove this comment later as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general builder is used in following way: 
Some class will use builder to create class. Simple

[image]

---

Now you have additional piece of complexity - caching. You can put caching inside Builder or one level higher inside Processor.

What are the implications of putting cache management inside builder:

- Builder does not have single responsibility anymore.
- It does not work how you would expect at first glance
- You are unable to create object without putting it into cache

These problems will not occur if you put cache management to separate class.

---

I would say that it is not terrible solution, but it certainly will decrease maintainability of your code.